# ngrx-store-localstorage allowedCommonJsDependencies warning

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using ngrx-store-localstorage in my app
and I got this warning:

> Warning:
> /Users/Me/angular-ngrx-material-standalone-starter/node_modules/ngrx-store-localstorage/fesm2022/ngrx-store-localstorage.mjs
> depends on 'deepmerge'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause
> optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

I try to add ngrx-store-localstorage in my angular.json
like:

```
{
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
   "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["ngrx-store-localstorage"],
    }
}
```

as the doc stated but the warning still exists.

Can you help me, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `deepmerge` to `allowedCommonJsDependencies` to get rid of the warning.